Fixing command conflict between packages
I have two packages, one with ProvidesPackage{pist}{kat}, the other with ProvidesPackage{negut}{kat}.
Both include the command \boldn.  Because a conflict naturally occurs can one add a condition to use boldn from negut.sty when pist.sty is also included ?
The file pist.sty
\ProvidesPackage{pist}[this]

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand {\boldn} {m}
  {
    {\boldmath \bfseries {#1}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

The file negut.sty
\ProvidesPackage{negut}[this]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand {\boldn} {m}
  {
    { \bfseries {#1}}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff


You should really provide an exampe as the details depend on the details not shown also it isn't clear what you mean by ProvidesPackage{pist}{kat} as \ProvidesPackage does not have two mandatory arguments.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can replace \NewDocumentCommand with \ProvideDocumentCommand then the first package loaded will impose its definition (or, alternatively, use \DeclareDocumentCommand, then the last package loaded will win).

why does neugut define this at all? \boldn is just a poor version of \textbf without the control over italic correction or support for math mode use.

you could make neugut do \let\boldn\@undefined\NewDocumentCommand {\boldn} {m}  then you won't get an error if pist has been loaded previously, but just removing the definition would be better.

Ok, suppose they are the same.  Users could use pist.sty on its own or  negut.sty on its own.  But not together,  I want to remove the conflict when a user calls both.

I would like users to have the ability to copy the files they need without lots of dependencies.  That is why I have same commands in both files.  But perhaps doing such a thing is wrong.  What do you think David ?

as I comment in the answer the specifics of making both commands available depend on the details of the command but it's hard to say anything about the example as \boldn serves no purpose at all in neugut as \textbf is already defined and  better.

What I need are some examples that can help me resolve conflicts without having to change the code in those files.  I agree \boldnnot to be a good example, but consider some command \bambi that only god knows what it does.

Is there any documentation I can read that discussed how to handle conflicts, handling multiple commands with same name etc.  It is a difficult topic to think about correctly.

there is no general answer. The code in my answer shows you how to define \bambi from the other package, but if the definition of \bambi assumes that the font setup from pist is in force but that has been changed to the font setup defined by neugut the \bambi command will be defined but produce the wrong character with no warning. If you are in control of both packages perhaps what you really want is to put all the shared code into  pist-neuget-base.sty  and have each of pist and neugut \RequirePackage{pist-neuget-base.} that will only be loaded once even if both packages loaded

Your negut.sty should probably not contain \ProvidesPackage{pist}[this]. | I suggest removing from pist.sty and negut.sty the things that form the intersection of pist.sty and negut.sty and having three packages instead of two: pist.sty and negut.sty and one package which contains what formerly was the intersection of pist.sty and negut.sty and which both in pist.sty and negut.sty is loaded via \RequirePackage.

Right, it should be \ProvidesPackage{negut}[this]

load one package then save the copy of boldn and undefine it
\NewCommandCopy\boldnA\boldn
\let\boldn\undefined
\ExpandArgs{c}\let{boldn code}\undefined

then load the second package
Now you have \boldnA and \boldn

This will make both commands defined, whether they work will depend on the actual definitions. If they are simple macros it will be fine, if they are math commands defined via \mathchardef the definition will depend on the entire math font setup and if both packages are defining say \fam3 as the main math font in different ways, saving (just) the command definition will not make a combined font loader.

How can I have the second package detect that the first package is used and undefine the one in the first package ?  I would like all this to be automatic.

you could use \@ifpackageloaded{...} but I would avoid that: you have to consider loading packages in various orders. Better to just make your definitions then suppress the other package eg how xcolor suppresses color

Suppress the other package completely ?  There are certain commands that I want to use from the first package.

@Bulldrive just load the first package from your second package then redefine/save the commands you want. like graphicx loads graphics then redefines some commands

Have added clarification in the question.

The better thing would be to make definitions then suppress the other package.  How can one do that.  By suppress, you mean suppress all functionality from the other package?  Would one not have to replicate the same code if you suppress it ?  And if you suppress it, why not just not call it in the first place ?

It seems to me that users would have to first load the first package, rename the conflicting commands, then load the second package.  Meaning, they have to figure out what conflicts and rename or undefine them themselves.  If only I could avoid having them handle such things and assist them a little bit. Perhaps  one can write a command that redefines or undefines them in some way?

You have re-written the question, but at the time I was addressing the usual case of an end user having conflicting packages and having to make that choice to resolve the conflicts. Your case seems to be that you are producing two conflicting packages at the same time, which really only has the answer don't do that. Put the shared code in a shared internal package as noted in comments under the question

A thing I noticed is the warning The command \boldn was undefined but not the associated commands \boldn code and/or \boldn defaults.

@Bulldrive sorry undefined the internal command to silence that warning, see update

So there are some internal boldn code and boldn defaults that are associated with the definition of a command ?  Everything starts becoming complicated.

Correct, I am producing two conflicting packages at the same time.  The reason is that I wanted to avoid having different command names.  Then giving preference of one over the other at run time.  It is more complicated than I thought.

@Bulldrive you should never need to get here. The code shown here is how to resolve a conflict between two packages both using \NewDocumentCommand so both can not be "new" but since it  turns out you have write access to both packages you can ensure that the situation never occurs. If the packages make sense to load both don't declare both packages make a new command.

@Bulldrive lots of packages intentionally define the same commands, eg amssymb and stix2 declare a similar set of math commands, but its simply an error to load both.  color and xcolor define similar commands but there xcolor totally over-writes color it's your choice how to handle these things.

If you use \DeclareDocumentCommand in negut.sty, the command will be defined whenever it was already set or not. The previous definition is lost.
\ProvidesPackage{negut}

\DeclareDocumentCommand {\boldn} {m}
  {
    { \bfseries {#1}}
  }

If you use \ProvideDocumentCommand in pist.sty, the command will be defined only if previously unset. If already defined, it will be left unchanged.
\ProvidesPackage{pist}

\ProvideDocumentCommand {\boldn} {m}
  {
    {\boldmath \bfseries {#1}}
  }

This will solve conflicts between the two packages, as negut definitions will always take precedence over pist ones. But take care of interactions with other packages, you lost all error messages.

@David, what do you think of such approach ?
